# Android Chrome Custom Tabs Reload

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

While using Webview, I can use reload() for refreshing the webpage. But in Chrome Custom Tabs, how i can reload the webpage? Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

currently there is no support in chrome custom tabs to programmatically trigger a page refresh.
If you happen to own the page which is being opened, you can cause a page refresh to happen via JS.